# How can I implement filter screen with two listview side by side?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have implemented master detail but it only works in tablets and in some cases landscape mode only. What can be done to implement it in mobile device?

Comment: what version on android studio are you on? Have you tried the implementation on emulated devices?

Comment: @elolelo Yes, I'm working on Android studio 3.5

Comment: I've also added image link. please check